# How many parameters does the vanilla Transformer have?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, transformer, attention-mechanism

The original Transformer paper ([Vaswani et al; 2017 NeurIPS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf)) describes the model architecture and the hyperparameters in quite some detail, but it misses to provide the exact (or even rough) model size in terms of parameters (model weights).

I could not find a source with a definite answer on this. Table 3 also mentions a `base` and a `big` model, but for none of them model size is given.

How many parameters does a `base` or a `big` Transformer model, according to the original implementation by Vaswani et al., have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table 3 has all the values of the hyper-parameters of the models.

See the image below, green are for the base and blue for the big model.

[image: Table 3]

You can use these to get the matrices sizes. For example for the multi-headed attention in section 3.2.2

[image: multi headed attention]

the matrix $W^{Q}_{i}\in\mathbb{R}^{d_{model}\times d_{k}}$, will have a dimension of $d_{model}\times d_{k} = 512\times 64$ for the base model, which is $32,768$ parameters.

For a single $head_{i}$, that value will be $\times 3 = 98,304$. For the multi-head, that value will be $\times h = \times 8 = 786,432$ parameters for the base model.

You can use the other values from Table 3 to figure out the rest of the model matrices. For examples, $d_{ff}$ is used in section 3.3. Table 3 says that the total of all parts of the model should be $65\times 10^6$ for the base model and $213\times 10^6$ for the big model.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Bruno Lubascher's answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/120363/73818) I [asked ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/share/0017ba6b-85c7-4cfa-9f8c-08202c29fb82) and double-checked its answer.

The fixed formula was:
$V \times d_{model} + V \times d_{model} + N \times (2 \times h \times 3 \times d_{model} \times d_k + 2 \times d_{model} \times d_{ff})$
for respectively:

- the token input embeddings
- the final layer (equivalent to a dot product with token output embeddings)
- the attention heads
- the feedforward networks.

Using the base values of the table (plus $V = 37000$ of vocabulary size), I got a total of 60M which was close enough to me to the 65M. Which means that token input/output embeddings make a total of 38M which is 58% of a total of 65M parameters.